# highcharts: Indent labels from pie-chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pie-chart

How can I remove this [indentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzFUX.png)?

How to make so that this [text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2zbM.png) is not crawled?

Sorry for bad English. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by this text is not crawled? Are you trying to pull data from the pie chart via a web crawler?

Comment: I mean that the data outside the border

Comment: You can set bigger margins - http://jsfiddle.net/xrst5pt3/2/ For moving data labels closer to connector, you can set [connectorPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cpie%3E.dataLabels.connectorPadding) to 0 - http://jsfiddle.net/xrst5pt3/3/

Comment: morganfree, thank you so much! You helped me a lot. I solved the problem this way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really [good example](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/aZ9VA/2/) of creating highcharts.
What you want is to manipulate the `plotOptions.column.dataLabels` object. See docs [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.dataLabels). See `overflow: String` and `x : Number`. You can change those values to solve your problem :)

Comment: Does not work these ways!
Here is the source code. Please look!
http://jsfiddle.net/xrst5pt3/

Comment: Giving it a try, yeah you're right. The x does move the labels. Is there any way you can just make the container larger? Also, you could also trim the labels to only be a certain length, that way, they wouldn't be overly large.

Comment: Another way to get by it would to be to alter `connectorWidth : number` and position the labels closer to the pie graph. Sorry I can't be of more help.